# What is the necessary and suffices condition to build an r -regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show what is necessary and suffices  to have an r-regular graph with n vertices.

where   $n  >  r+1$

One way is to build that r-regular graph with n vertices ...

Comment: The sum of the degrees must be even, so $nr$ must be even.

Comment: Number of edges must be $nr/2$.

Comment: @Aravind you right but is it the only condition to have an r-regular graph? if so we need a proof...
Thank  you

Comment: @Niloofar_jz Yes, it is the only condition.  Have you tried constructing it yourself?  I suggest first trying the case where $r$ is even, then the case where $r$ is odd and $n$ is even.  Hint: both can be done with a circulant graph (Cayley graph on $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$)..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By the Handshaking lemma you also have 
$$n \cdot r =2 E$$

This adds a second restriction in some cases.

If $r=2k< n$ regular graphs the following way:

Draw the $2n+1$ vertices on the circle, and connect every vertex to $k$ neighbours at the left and $k$ neighbours on the right.

[Or equivalently label the vertices $0,1,2,3,..,,2n \pmod{2n+1}$ and put an edge $ij$ exactly if $i-j \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 2,.., \pm k\} \pmod{2n+1}$.]

Now if $r=2k+1$ then $n=2m$ is even. Split the vertices in two groups of $m$.

If $r < m$ then you can start from $K_{m,m}$ and create regular graphs by using Hall matching Theorem, and removing matchings. This method creates regular Bipartide graphs with the degrees decreasing exactly by 1 in each step.

If $r \geq m$ then you can use induction. Each of the two groups of $m$ vertices contains a $r-m+1$ regular graphs by the induction. Glue two copies of this with $K_{m,m}$, which increases each degree by $m-1$.